# LWJGL: JVM crashing with error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, opengl, crash, rendering, lwjgl

While trying to set up a minimal reproducable example using LWJGL because my original question was closed, I ran into a problem I didn't have originally (Originally it was just not displaying), which is that the JVM now crashes with an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` error during the `glDrawArrays()` call.

I don't know what could be causing this, but I've tried for example initializing the vertex attribute pointers each frame. There is also no debug information or errors logged, while I did set up an error callback and I think a debug message callback.

**All of the code:**

```java
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MinimalExample {

    private static String readResource(String res) {
        try {
            InputStream is = MinimalExample.class.getResourceAsStream(res);
            String s = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            is.close();
            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    // vertex data buffer
    private static final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4096);

    // shader program
    static int program;

    // render objects
    static int vao;
    static int vbo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set buffer limit
        buf.limit(4096);

        // init glfw and create window
        GLFW.glfwInit();
        long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Hello", 0, 0);

        // create GL
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback(System.out);
        GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.out));

        // create vertex objects
        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        vbo = GL30.glGenBuffers();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 0);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        // compile and link shaders
        int vertexShader   = GL30.glCreateShader(GL30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragmentShader = GL30.glCreateShader(GL30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GL30.glShaderSource(vertexShader,   readResource("/test.vsh"));
        GL30.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, readResource("/test.fsh"));
        GL30.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        GL30.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        program = GL30.glCreateProgram();
        GL30.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GL30.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GL30.glLinkProgram(program);

        // render loop
        while (!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            // poll events
            GLFW.glfwPollEvents();

            // clear screen
            GL30.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL30.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // render
            render();

            // swap buffers
            GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
    }

    static void render() {
        // put vertex data
        // manual to simulate graphics library
        putVec3(0.25f, 0.25f, 1f); putVec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        putVec3(0.75f, 0.25f, 1f); putVec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        putVec3(0.50f, 0.75f, 1f); putVec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // bind program
        GL30.glUseProgram(program);

        // bind vertex array
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // upload graphics data and draw
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL30.glBufferData(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf, GL30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL30.glDrawArrays(GL30.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        // reset vertex data buffer
        buf.position(0);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    static void putVec3(float x, float y, float z) {
        buf.putFloat(x).putFloat(y).putFloat(z);
    }

    static void putVec4(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
        buf.putFloat(x).putFloat(y).putFloat(z).putFloat(z);
    }

}
```

**The full JVM error log (`hs_err_pidX.log`):** [pastes.dev](https://pastes.dev/t9NGbonz1L)

For context, I'm running this with JDK 17 from IntelliJ directly. Here is the `build.gradle` file if you want to check the dependencies: [build.gradle (GitHub)](https://github.com/orbyfied/opticum/blob/master/test-lwjgl/build.gradle)

Comment: It sounds like an out-of-bounds error on the C(++?) side of lwjgl. I'd double check that the indices you are using are correct. It would also help to point out the line that causes this issue (either through a stack trace, or process of elimination. You can do the latter by removing half of the code, seeing if the issue persists, and then either adding half back or removing another half until you find the line).

Comment: I can read off the line from the JVM crash log, it happens in Java on line 105, with the `glDrawArrays()` call. Thing is that I did not specify or bind any indecies, I thought OpenGL could just generate those from the primitives given and the vertex positions.

Comment: `GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 0);` looks suspect. Shouldn't the `7 * 4` be a value in bytes? And the last parameter contain an offset the size of the position data?

Comment: You way want to copy the code into your question, so that it's self-contained and will remain useful to others even if the link has become invalid. SO will add scrollbars to the code snippet, so the length won't be an issue.

Comment: Alright I'll put the code in the question body in a second, also 7 * 4 stands for 7x 4 bytes because we have 7 floats per vertex, seems right to me.

Comment: Could be correct. I'm more familiar with the C interface where that value has to be multiplied by `sizeof(GL_FLOAT)` as well.

Comment: oh wait i forgot stackoverflow makes the code scrolling, i thought it would be a lock block of text

Comment: Have you tried using `GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 3 * 4);`? (For attribute 1 only)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249492/discussion-between-orbyfied-and-yun).